# Необходимо найти последнее вхождение символа в строке и удалить все, что после него

Tags: php, строки

Есть строка "qwauireaau!hhed!sdvg". Необходимо найти последнее вхождение символа "!" и удалить все, что следует после него. Т.е. в итоге строка должна иметь вид "qwauireaau!hhed!". Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать

Comment: А какая проблема? Найти индекс последнего вхождения `"!"` или удалить кусок строки? (Не говоря о том, что можно и регулярное выражение.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$tag = "qwauireaau!hhed!sdvg";

echo preg_replace('/[^!]+$/s', '', $tag);;
```

2

```
$tag = "qwauireaau!hhed!sdvg";

$tag = explode('!', $tag);

$tag[count($tag)-1] = "";

echo implode('!', $tag);
```

Comment: Первый вариант не прокатит на строке `$tag = "qwauireaau!hhed!sdv@g"`

Comment: @VladD я знаю, preg_replace('/[^!]+$/s', '', $tag);;

Comment: @lampa: +1, но у вас в комментарии правильно, а в ответе `!^`

Comment: @VladD на работе что-то душно. Уф.

Comment: @lampa: ничего, скоро Новый Год! :) (А может, ну её, эту работу?)

Comment: @VladD до 25 числа недолго осталось, протяну!) Дальше в баньку на неделю невылазно. Заслуженный, так сказать, отдых)) А работу не, нельзя. Премию хочется ^^

Comment: @lampa: эх, и я бы в баньку :) когда там обещали конец света? вот бы он наступил, только не так, чтобы планета взорвалась, а чтобы электричество вырубили. Желательно только на работе!

Comment: @VladD да вырубят у нас, ага) Дизельки за окном ждут своего часа, недождутся никак)

Answer (score 3):

```
echo substr('qwauireaau!hhed!sdvg',0,strrpos('qwauireaau!hhed!sdvg', '!'));
```